# Installing instagrapi on Raspberry Pi VSC

Tags: python, visual-studio, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to run the python library 'instagrapi' from my raspberry pi 4B, with VSCode, and am having massive issues getting the library to install. The python version on the pi is 3.11.2.

After installing pip and making sure that my terminal is in the folder containing the .py file I'm trying to run, I've run the following

```
python -m venv /venv
```

At this point, an venv file appears in the same folder containing the .py file. Then I use

```
source venv/vin/activate
```

At this point, the next terminal line has (venv) in front of it.

Then I used

```
pip install instagrapi
```

It runs through several packages, installing dependencies, etc, and eventually finishes.

Then I run the code, an I get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'instagrapi'
```

I've tried looking at a bunch of tutorials on how to set up a venv, but it seems like I'm still screwing up somewhere. TIA for the help!

EDIT: It works after I use "pip install instagrapi --break-system-packages" outside of the venv, but I'd really like to be able to run it in venv.

Comment: You can check if it is installed in your venv using 'pip list'. If it is, one possible cause of the problem is that when you try to run your program, you are running a different Python environment. In Visual Studio Code, for example, you need to select a virtual environment explicitly, and the same may be true for other IDEs

Comment: I wasn't able to get one working with the CLI, but I was able to set up a venv by clicking the "3.11.2" in the bottom right hand corner, and creating a venv with the built-in prompts.